# Cordova firebase google auth

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, oauth

I'm trying to implement Google Auth in a cordova (phonegap) app.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova?hl=en-419

- I have created an auth domain in firebase xxxx.firebaseapp.com
- My app is agregated to firebase (I'm was using firebase for analytics) in the same app.
- I have enabled Firebase Dynamic Links, and I can view my domain xxxx.page.link
- I have enabled google sign method.
- I have installed all required plugins
- In my config.xml:

  ```
  <universal-links>
  <host name="xxxx.page.link" scheme="https" />
  <host name="xxxx.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
  <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
  </host>
  </universal-links>
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
  ```

My login method:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
                console.log("hola");
                return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
}).then(function(result) {
                // This gives you a Google Access Token.
                // You can use it to access the Google API.
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                // The signed-in user info.
                var user = result.user;
                afterLoginGoogle(user);
}).catch(function(error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log("error1 "+ errorMessage);   //Error log!!!!

            });
});
```

When I execute my login method, a new chrome tab is launched, and I put my google user and password. Then, tab is closed and app is showed again, but I allways get an error in my console:
"error1 the redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing."

the first time I got this error I put this code when the app loads:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token.
        // You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
        console.log("Despues");
        afterLoginGoogle(user);
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("Despues"+errorMessage);
    });
```

I've tried catch all Dinamic links events,to test, but no event is recieved:

```
universalLinks.subscribe(null, function(eventData) {
            alert('Did launch application from the link: ' + eventData.url);
});
```

but it never run :(

Can anyone help me please. I'm exausted whith this situation.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to post an answer to my own question, because it can be usefull for other people.

First time,  if yoy follow the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova?hl=en-419 , it works. But...

Cordova universal link plugin has an issue whith newest cordova versions, not solved yet: https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/133

You can fix the plugin manually:
In this file: ./plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/android/manifestWriter.js
change at line 21:

```
var pathToManifest = path.join(cordovaContext.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms', 'android', 'AndroidManifest.xml');
```

to:

```
var pathToManifest = path.join(
    cordovaContext.opts.projectRoot,
    'platforms',
    'android',
    'app',
    'src',
    'main',
    'AndroidManifest.xml');
```

And, if you are having problems with universal links, take a look to the manifest resulting file: platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="XXXXXXX.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="XXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com" android:scheme="https" android:path="/__/auth/callback"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

And check if this configuration it's equivalentu whith your config.xml. You must not change Manifest file!!! It's only for check it. If not, check if you have more than one annotation about universal links in the config.xml.

Comment: im getting the same error, im trying what you recommended, but get this error Error: Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined

Comment: try executing "phonegap clean" or "cordova clean"

Answer (score 0):

Was anyone successfully able to authenticate users after the redirect? I get nothing back from the DL Event Listeners and a Firebbase Error: `The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing.`

Comment: If you are getting that error, probably you have a problem with your Universal links configuration. I spent several hours trying to find whats the problem, but finally I had a configuration error in the config.xml file.

Comment: Discovered that there was a mistake in my Universal Links setup in the config. My callback URL was wrong haha